# Show intersection POI when getting shortest paths

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

What I'm trying to do is get K shortest path with details to show all poi that we travel trough.

The problem is I'm trying to add intersections to the POI but need to move it off the end of the edge else `pgr_withPointsKSP` fails to run. But by doing this it moves it off the intersection and will not show up in details for some paths.

current query

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_path_poi (
  vid integer,
  pid serial,
  fraction double precision,
  asset_id character varying(30),
  address character varying(250),
  point_type text,
  geom geometry
);


-- Add network features to poi table
WITH network_vertices AS (
  SELECT source AS id FROM tmp_path_network
  UNION ALL
  SELECT target AS id FROM tmp_path_network
)
, points AS (
  SELECT point_type, geom
  FROM (
    (
      SELECT the_geom AS geom, 'deadend' AS point_type
      FROM network_vertices_pgr
      WHERE cnt = 1
        AND id IN (SELECT id FROM network_vertices))
      UNION ALL
    (
      SELECT the_geom AS geom, 'join' AS point_type
      FROM network_vertices_pgr
      WHERE cnt = 2
        AND id IN (SELECT id FROM network_vertices))
      UNION ALL
    (
      SELECT the_geom AS geom, 'intersection' AS point_type
      FROM network_vertices_pgr
      WHERE cnt >= 3
        AND id IN (SELECT id FROM network_vertices))
  ) AS tbl_a
)
, tbl_sub AS (
  SELECT closest_feature.id AS vid, g2.point_type, closest_feature.geom AS vgeom, g2.geom AS pgeom
  FROM points AS g2
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT id, st_distance(g1.geom, g2.geom) AS dist, geom
    FROM tmp_path_network AS g1
    WHERE st_dwithin(g1.geom, g2.geom, 1.0)
    ORDER BY g1.geom <-> g2.geom
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS closest_feature
)

INSERT INTO tmp_path_poi (vid, fraction, point_type, geom)
SELECT
  vid,
  CASE st_linelocatepoint(vgeom, pgeom)
    WHEN 0
      THEN 0.000001
    WHEN 1
      THEN 0.999999
    ELSE
      st_linelocatepoint(vgeom, pgeom)
  END   AS fraction,
  point_type,
  pgeom AS geom
FROM tbl_sub;


SELECT *
FROM pgr_withPointsKSP(
  'SELECT id, source, target, cost, cost as reverse_cost FROM tmp_path_network ORDER BY id',
  'SELECT pid, vid as edge_id, fraction FROM tmp_path_poi',
  (SELECT (pid * -1) FROM tmp_path_poi WHERE point_type = 'start' ORDER BY pid ASC LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT (pid * -1) FROM tmp_path_poi WHERE point_type = 'end' ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 1),
  1,
  directed := false,
  details := true
)
```

[image]

In this image path A-C doesn't show the intersection poi, but A-B and B-C will.

Is there a way I can get the intersection poi to show in detail for all paths?

Comment: The *withPoints* family of functions is meant to be used on additional nodes that are **not** present in the graph - it seems your interpretation of a '*POI*' correlates very closely to nodes that **are** present in the graph, i.e. that are *primary graph nodes*!? A plain call to `pgr_KSP` will return all primary graph nodes that it traverses.

Comment: Thanks @geozelot, you are correct there was no need to add the nodes to the poi table and the geom/detail for them can be found in the *_vertices_pgr table with reference to node column returned by the ```pgr_withPointsKSP``` or ```pgr_KSP``` functions. Can you post this as a answer so I can accept it, thanks.

Comment: no time...but it is perfectly fine to self-answer (and accept) your own questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From geozelot's comment, there was no need to add the intersection, joins or dead-ends to the poi database as they are already part of the *_vertices_pgr database and can be referenced from the node column of the ksp function.